# get href attrib of anchor element from code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, anchor, href

hi my dear friends :
how can i get href attrib of anchor element from code behind in asp.net? (c#)

why the below codes do n't work?
aspx :

```
            <a runat="server" id="lightbox" href='<%# GetImageurl() %>'>
            <asp:Image ID="imgInrpvEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Admin/Unknown.png" />
            </a>
```

code behind :

```
protected string GetImageurl()
{
    return "/Images/Admin/Unknown.png";
}
```

note : my pages base on master & content pages + In those content pages i have multiview & upper Anchor is inside a view in content page...

best regards

Comment: what is rendered to the browser?

Comment: hi dear @Mel -> there is no href after render!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove

```
runat="server"
```

and use this syntax

```
<%= GetImageurl() %>
```

If you can't remove runat="server" you can do it code-side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lightbox.Attributes.Add("href", GetImageurl());
    }
```

**Update**

If you want to use your actual syntax I think you have to call DataBind method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lightbox.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your tag is wrong?

try `<%= GetImageurl() %>`

http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your page load sequence, you want to have:

```
lightbox.NavigateUrl = GetImageurl());
```

Also, you don't need to include an asp:Image, just do this right after the above:

```
lightbox.ImageUrl = "http://somewhere.jpg"
```